# Read Resources from SD card

Tags: android

Suppose we have downloaded some files from somewhere to the some resources folder on the SD card. Now, let's be able to use the downloaded. Jpg image as the background, and play audio clip. How to implement reading data from the SD card or phone memory (com.example.app or etc folder)? For example, if resources located into the application, then I read so

```
layout.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.img);
```

And I need instead of `R.drawable.img` i must read from an SD card or phone memory. The sound of my own class, but the principle of reading should be the same

```
sound = getAudioClip (R.raw.sound);
```

where instead of `R.raw.sound` must-read SD card or phone memory.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sample to know how to fetch and display images from the SD card
[Images from SD Card](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2009/11/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html)

Comment: No it's example with Adapters. I must use this images on buttons and layouts and sounds on player.